# How to make sure Qt Widget.repaint has finished running?

Tags: c++, c, qt, graphics, computer-vision

I am currently having a problem with Qt graphics view framework namely, I want to clear my QGraphicScene background color and then run a function to take a webcam picture. So far when I use QWidget.repaint the screen only got repaint after about 1 second and by then the camera function has been called and the image captured is always off. Here is how my code currently look like.

```
//Scene is a QGraphicScene
//View is a QGraphicView
//Camera is a camera object
Scene.setBackgroundBrush(Qt::Blue)
View.repaint()
Camera.Capture()
```

I have tried wrapping the `repaint()` call with another function and use signal and slot call but it still fail. I want to know if there is a way to pause the program until the screen has been refreshed.

Comment: Does `Camera.Capture()` actually trigger an external webcam to take a picture of your screen?

Comment: Yes. The Camera.Capture() function trigger an external webcam to take a picture of my screen. But the problem is what I capture from the webcam is not the same as what I am expecting the screen to show.

Answer (score 0):

A `QGraphicsView` has a bit more going on than most `QWidget` subclasses and I'm not familiar enough with it to say what is going on for sure but I might venture a guess that your problem is related to the fact that the scene is actually rendered onto the view port widget. Perhaps calling `viewport->repaint()` will give you the results you are looking for?

Also, unless you really need to be using the webcam in this scenario, you could call `::render()` on your scene and pass it a `QImage` which you could save directly to a file.

Comment: I definitely need to use a webcam in this case. The whole point of the program I am making is using the virtual scene of application to remove the background captured by the camera.

I have also tried viewport->repaint() but the screen rendering is still lagging behind.